# Description matching in record linkage using Machine learning Approach

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, apache-spark-mllib, record-linkage

We are working on record linkage project.

In simple terms, we are searching product in database just by looking at the similarity of description. It is a very interesting problem to solve, but currently the machine learning approach, what we have adopted is resulting in very low accuracy. If you can suggest something very lateral approach it will help our project a lot.

Input description

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------+
 | ID | description                                  |
-+----|----------------------------------------------+
 |  1 |delta t17267-ss ara 17 series shower trim ss  |
 |  2 |delta t14438 chrome lahara tub shower trim on |
 |  3 |delta t14459 trinsic tub/shower trim          |
 |  4 |delta t17497 cp cassidy tub/shower trim only  |
 |  5 |delta t14497-rblhp cassidy tub & shower trim  |
 |  6 |delta t17497-ss cassidy 17 series tub/shower  |
-+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Description in Database

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID | description                                                                                         | 
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | delta monitor17 ara&reg; shower trim 2 gpm 1 lever handle stainless commercial                      |                       
| 2 | delta monitor 14 lahara&reg; tub and shower trim 2 gpm 1 handle chrome plated residential           |                        
| 3 | delta monitor 14 trinsic&reg; tub and shower trim 2 gpm 1 handle chrome plated residential          |                        
| 4 | delta monitor17 addison&trade; tub and shower trim 2 gpm 1 handle chrome plated domestic residential|                       
| 5 | delta monitor 14 cassidy&trade; tub and shower trim 2 gpm venetian bronze                           |                        
| 6 | delta monitor 17 addison&trade; tub and shower trim 2 gpm 1 handle stainless domestic residential   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Background information

1.The records in database are fundamentally very near because of which it causing huge issue.

2.There are around 2 million records in database, but search space gets reduced when we search for specific manufacturer the search space gets reduced to few hundreds.

3.The records in “Input description” with records ID 1 is same as the record in “Description in Database” with record ID 1( That we know using manual approach.)

4.we are used **random forest** train to predict.

Current approach

1. We are tokenized the description
2. Remove stopwords
3. Added abbreviation information
4. For each record pair we calculate scores from different string metric like jacard, sorendice, cosine, average of all this scores are calculated.
5. Then we calculate the score for manufacturer Id using jaro winker metric method.
6. So if there are 5 records of a manufacturer in “input description” and 10 records for a manufacturer in “database” the total combination is 50 records pairs that is 10 pairs per record, which results in scores which are very near. We have considered top 4 record pair from each set of 10 pairs. In the case for a record pair, where there is similar score for more than one record pair, we have considered all of them.

   7.We arrive at the following learning data set format.

   ```
   |----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------- +--------------+-----------+
   |ISMatch | Descrption average score  |manufacturer ID score| jacard score of description | sorensenDice | cosine(3) |
   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |1       | 1:0.19                   | 2:0.88               |3:0.12                       | 4:0.21       | 5:0.23    |
   |0       | 1:0.14                   |2:0.66                |3:0.08                       | 4:0.16       |  5:0.17   |
   |0       | 1:0.14                   |2:0.68                |3:0.08                       |4:0.15        |  5:0.19   |
   |0       | 1:0.14                   |2:0.58                |3:0.08                       |4:0.16        |  5:0.16   |
   |0       | 1:0.12                   |2:0.55                |3:0.08                       |4:0.14        |  5:0.14   |
   |--------+--------------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
   ```

   We train the above dataset. When predict it in real time using the same approach the accuracy is very low.
   Please suggest any other alternative approach,

   we planned to use TF-IDF but initial investigation reveals it also may not improve the accuracy by huge terms.

Comment: This is not a spark-java issue, please remove this tag. apache-spark != spark-java